# Will any errors be thrown out while executing START TRANSACTION in MyISAM table?

Tags: mysql, transactions, myisam, acid

I tried the start transaction on a MyISAM table, and it replied "Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)".

But I'm not sure if the same thing will happen on all versions of MySQL.

Is there any spec about the behavior in non-transaction mode of those queries which involve being in transaction ?

Comment: How did you do this? Please show the SQL -

Comment: Just execute the query "START TRANSACTION;"

Comment: @ymfoi Well, when you do that (i.e. START TRANSACTION) you do not specify any table, so it will always work, even if you have only MyISAM tables in the database that is currently in use.

Comment: ... which was what I meant with "show the SQL"

Comment: @SoboLAN Thanks for clarification of the queries. I've been confused for quite a time.

Comment: @EugenRieck Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, no error or warnng will be raised. WHen you start a transaction, you do it for all transactional engines available, not for any specific table.

You can run queries on tables using both transactional and non-transactional engines within a transaction, but of course only changes performed on tableswith transactional engines will need to be commit/rollback.

Queries performed on tables with non-transactional engines will just have an immediate effect as usual.

Comment: @ymfoi, see here for more details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html ... basically, when you perform queries (both inside and outside of transactions) on tables that don't have transactional support, they work in auto_commit=1 mode ...